# Inhomogeneous wave equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

How do I solve the following partial differential equation:

> $$f_{tt}-A^2f_{xx}=-B^2f$$
>   for $f(x,t)$?

Comment: Do you have boundary and initial conditions or just the pde as given?

Comment: What is the domain? The strategy for solving PDE often depends heavily on the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Separation of variables seems like a natural thing to do.
$$f = T(t)X(x)$$
Then the equation naturally splits into pieces. Both will give you sets of solutions. To proceed further you'd need to use boundary/initial conditions.